# MySQL issue on INSERT ... SELECT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, last-insert-id

In MySQL, I have `INSERT ... SELECT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query as below:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user ( name
                         , mobile
                         , email
                         , sex
                         , username
                         , password
                         )
          SELECT u.name
               , u.mobile
               , u.email
               , u.sex
               , u.username
               , u.password
          FROM import_user u 
          WHERE u.name <> '' AND u.mobile <> ''
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
              user_id     = LAST_INSERT_ID(user_id),
              name        = VALUES (name),
              mobile      = VALUES (mobile),
              email       = VALUES (email),
              sex         = VALUES (sex)";
```

UPDATE:
This is the result from above query.

```
select user_id, role_id, name,sex, mobile from user;
+---------+---------------------------+--------+-------------+
| user_id | name                      | sex    | mobile      | 
+---------+---------------------------+--------+-------------+
|     131 | Name 1                    | Male   | 435345345   |
|     132 | Name 2                    | Male   | 43543534    |
|     133 | Name 3                    | Male   | 45645644    |
|     134 | Name 4                    | Male   | 5345        |
|     135 | Name 5                    | Male   | 5465475     |
|     136 | Name 6                    | Male   | 56456546    |
+---------+---------------------------+--------+-------------+
```

Now I want to create an array of the `user_id` of either the insert or the update the records.

So, my expecting array should be

```
$uid = [131,132,133,134,135,136]
```

I tried it something like this, but it doesn't work for me. That mean I can get only one id.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$uids[] = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

So, May I know Is there a way to create an array from the effected user ID of the above query running?

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: MySQL does not support RETURNING clause. You may use according triggers pack which gathers needed information somewhere (user-defined variable, lo table, etc.) then query to this data.

Comment: @Akina, Sir, Can I see an example of your suggestion?

Comment: which database you are using ? MySQL ? MariaDB has this feature: see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/

Comment: @BerndBuffen. On localhost I have MariaDB, but on liveserver it has MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEMO:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
>                    category INT, 
>                    value INT,
>                    UNIQUE (category, value) );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER tr_ai
> AFTER INSERT ON test
> FOR EACH ROW 
> SET @ids_array := CONCAT_WS(',', @ids_array, NEW.id);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER tr_au
> AFTER UPDATE ON test
> FOR EACH ROW 
> SET @ids_array := CONCAT_WS(',', @ids_array, NEW.id);
> ```

> ```
> SET @ids_array := NULL;
> INSERT INTO test (category, value)
> VALUES (1,11), (2,22);
> SELECT * FROM test;
> SELECT @ids_array;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | category | value
> -: | -------: | ----:
>  1 |        1 |    11
>  2 |        2 |    22
>
> | @ids_array |
> | :--------- |
> | 1,2        |
> ```

> ```
> SET @ids_array := NULL;
> INSERT INTO test (category, value)
> VALUES (1,111), (2,22)
> ON DUPLICATE KEY 
> UPDATE value = NULL;
> SELECT * FROM test;
> SELECT @ids_array;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | category | value
> -: | -------: | ----:
>  1 |        1 |    11
>  3 |        1 |   111
>  2 |        2 |  null
>
> | @ids_array |
> | :--------- |
> | 3,2        |
> ```

> ```
> -- do not reset @ids_array
> INSERT INTO test (id, category, value)
> VALUES (1,4,44), (22,2,22)
> ON DUPLICATE KEY 
> UPDATE value = NULL;
> SELECT * FROM test;
> SELECT @ids_array;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | category | value
> -: | -------: | ----:
>  1 |        1 |  null
>  3 |        1 |   111
>  2 |        2 |  null
> 22 |        2 |    22
>
> | @ids_array |
> | :--------- |
> | 3,2,1,22   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=de3f8d3abce529281b4767725aa5f130)*